# Use cookies data as site search keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, liquid

Hi I'm looking to a way to collect user navigation keywords stored in the browser as search keywords in the current site view, let's say a person is looking for socks, shirt, jeans and just landed on your site I want the site to:

- pre fill the search form with suggested searched keywords.
- as they browse site content I would show a search result based on searched keywords and site visited pages and collect page main keywords show render search at the bottom.

I'm really looking for an idea to get started, I would presume jquery.cookies is a good way to get started and add some JavaScript to it to collect data but how?....

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think cookies is not best way for store a user looking for. You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage instead. To base search result on theese keywords you can add it manualy in search ajax from localStorage . But if you want to work with cookies - you can take small jquery plugin https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ .